# How to get the build number at runtime?

Tags: java, android

I'm writing a project and I need to get a phone build number.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to get that from [Build.DISPLAY](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#DISPLAY)

Comment: what about dependency like aar library?